# Reference methods from static member

Tags: python

So I have a class with a couple of (normal) methods. Depending on a value I want to call different methods. This behavior of choosing  methods is static (same for all instantiation of the classes. How would you recommend doing this?

Will the answer change on best way to achieve this if the state of an instantiation is constant and never changes after initialization?

Example:

```
PLUS = 0
MINUS = 1
OPERATIONS = [PLUS, MINUS]

class Generator(object):

    operations = {
        PLUS: self.plus,    # Not possible
        MINUS: self.minus,
    }

    def __init__(self, state):
        self._state = state

    def plus(self, a, b):
        # Depends on state
        return a + b

    def minus(self, a, b):
        return a - b if self._state else b - a

    def generate(self):
        a, b = give_me_numbers()
        for op in OPERATIONS:
            print self.operations[op](a, b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PLUS = 0
MINUS = 1
OPERATIONS = [PLUS, MINUS]

class Generator:
    operations = {}

    def __init__(self, state):
        self._state = state

    @classmethod
    def init_operations(cls):
        cls.operations = {
            PLUS:  cls.plus,    
            MINUS:  cls.minus
        }

    def plus(self, a, b):
        # Depends on state
        return a + b

    def minus(self, a, b):
        return a - b if self._state else b - a


    def generate(self):
        a, b = 5, 10
        for op in self.operations:
            print( self.operations[op](self, a, b) )

gen = Generator(1)
gen.init_operations()
gen.generate()
```

In order for `operations` to store functions of a class definition it can't be done at the top of a class like you have done. This is because the parser won't find the functions you're referring to because it hasn't parsed them yet.  So instead I've added a 'static' init_operations().

Note these operations are stored as unbound methods (since it's called from within a static); therefore when calling these functions it is necessary to include the `self` variable as the 1st argument.

Comment: Seems like a good solution. Is it equivalent to EOL's answer?

Comment: his is equivalent to mine   :)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to turn operations into a method:

```
    def operations(self, op):
        dictMethods = {
            "PLUS" : self.plus
            "MINUS" : self.minus
        }
        return dictMethods[op]
```

Then call it like:

```
self.operations(op)(a, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do actually works (there is no need for a more complicated solution), but you have to (1) write the dictionary definition of `operations` properly (with `:` instead of `=`) and (2) put its definition when it can be understood (after the methods that it refers to are defined):

```
PLUS = 0
MINUS = 1
OPERATIONS = [PLUS, MINUS]

class Generator(object):

    def __init__(self, state):
        self._state = state

    def plus(self, a, b):
        # Depends on state
        return a + b

    def minus(self, a, b):
        return a - b if self._state else b - a

    def generate(self):
        a, b = give_me_numbers()
        for op in OPERATIONS:
            print operations[op](a, b)

    operations = {  # plus and minus are defined, at this point
        PLUS: plus,
        MINUS: minus
    }
```

Side notes:

- Note the `Generator(object)` syntax (not `Generator()`)—or simply `Generator`, in Python 3.
- You might want check out the `enum` module, which handles the constants `PLUS`, `MINUS` and `OPERATIONS` that you define in a clean and convenient way.

**PS**: As PM 2Ring noted, using the values from `operations` can be done through `self.operations[op](self, a, b)`. I would personally do `Generator.operations[op](self, a, b)`, since `operations` is not specific to any instance and is instead a dictionary associated with the `Generator` class.

Comment: I believe I have to call the functions and pass a reference to self as well? `print operations[op](self, a, b)` am I right?

Comment: That gives me `NameError: global name 'operations' is not defined` on `print operations[op](a, b)` in Python 2.6.6. But this works properly: `print self.operations[op](self, a, b)`

Comment: @Moberg: Yes, you _do_ need to explicitly pass `self`, since the methods in `operations[op]` are class methods. Without a reference to `self` it's impossible for them to know what class instance to access in order to evaluate `self.state`.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Right. Technically, though, `operations[op]` is an  _unbound_ method, not a class method (which is a method that takes the class as a first argument).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slight modification to Richard's code that automatically calls the `init_operations` method the first time you instantiate a `Generator`.

```
class Generator:
    def __init__(self, state):
        self._state = state
        if not hasattr(self, 'operations'):
            self.init_operations()

    @classmethod
    def init_operations(cls):
        cls.operations = {
            PLUS: cls.plus,
            MINUS: cls.minus,
        }

    def plus(self, a, b):
        # Depends on state
        return a + b

    def minus(self, a, b):
        return a - b if self._state else b - a

    def generate(self):
        a, b = give_me_numbers()
        for op in self.operations:
            print self.operations[op](self, a, b)
```

Here's an alternative that makes `operations` a plain instance attribute. This wastes a little bit of space, but it means you don't need to explicitly pass `self` when you call an operation.

```
class Generator(object):
    def __init__(self, state=False):
        self._state = state
        self.operations = {
            PLUS: self.plus,
            MINUS: self.minus
        }

    def plus(self, a, b):
        # Depends on state
        return a + b

    def minus(self, a, b):
        return a - b if self._state else b - a

    def generate(self):
        a, b = give_me_numbers()
        for op in OPERATIONS:
            print self.operations[op](a, b)
```

And finally, this variation uses the method names to identify the operations instead of integers.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from random import seed, randint

def give_me_numbers():
    a, b = randint(1, 99), randint(1, 99)
    print 'a=%d, b=%d' % (a, b)
    return a, b


OPERATIONS = ('plus', 'minus')

class Generator(object):
    def __init__(self, state=False):
        self._state = state

    def plus(self, a, b):
        # Depends on state
        return a + b

    def minus(self, a, b):
        return a - b if self._state else b - a

    def operations(self, op):
        return getattr(self, op)

    def generate(self):
        a, b = give_me_numbers()
        for op in OPERATIONS:
            #print getattr(self, op)(a, b)
            print self.operations(op)(a, b)    

seed(42)

g1 = Generator(False)
g1.generate()

g2 = Generator(True)
g2.generate()
```

**output**

```
a=64, b=3
67
-61
a=28, b=23
51
5
```

You don't *really* need the `operations` method here - I just left it in to stay (relatively) consistent with the OP code. Instead, you can just call `getattr(self, op)(a, b)` directly. OTOH, it *is* cleaner to supply the `operations` method if you want to call it from outside the class.